# How to (manually) delete old artifacts?

Tags: buildmaster

I'm running BuildMaster version 4.8.6 and I'd like to delete old build artifacts.

This question (on the BuildMaster's maker's Q&A section of their site) – [Release/Build History](http://inedo.com/support/questions/483) – mentions that, besides a trigger in a beta extension and a 'release archiving' feature that may or may not have been implemented, old artifacts "need to be deleted manually".

How do I delete an artifact manually? Is there anything to it other than just deleting the relevant files and directories under the *BuildMaster\Artifacts\* directory?

Answer (score 0):

I asked this same question on the BuildMaster's maker's Q&A section of their site:

- [How to (manually) delete old artifacts? | Support Q & A | Inedo](http://inedo.com/support/questions/4777)

Based on [the answer](http://inedo.com/support/questions/4777#inline-post-4779) on the question there, here are steps to manually delete a single artifact:

1. From a (any) BuildMaster page, go to the *Settings & Administration* page.
2. In the "System Settings" group, click "Administrative Edits".
3. In the "Artifacts" group, click "Purge Artifact".
4. In the "Purge Build Artifact" popup, pick the relevant "Application", "Release", "Build", and "Artifact".
5. Click the "Purge Build Artifact" button.